# HP DV6 2011 Brightness Keys Do Not Work

Tags: monitor, brightness, dv6

I've searched around and no solutions seem to work that worked for older models. Not sure what to do next.

I'm unable to change my brightness with the keys on the keyboard. I can however use the GNOME power management preferences dialog to do so and can use e.g.

```
echo 10 > /sys/devices/virtual/backlight/acpi_video0/brightness
```

And everything works great. When running xev I get no output for the brightness button presses or releases, and I don't have /proc/acpi/LCD or anything related to the screen.

Any help would be appreciated and I can post any relevant system information if it will help, just let me know what to do.

Here's the [Pastebin link to acpidump.txt](http://pastebin.com/myUAu10R) as requested.

Comment: Hi Daniel, please include more specific machine information in your question. You can lookup that on the bottom of your laptop. If possible, install `acpidump` and run `sudo acpidump > acpidump.txt`. Put the contents of acpidump.txt on pastebin and add the link to your question.

Comment: dv6-3025dx

http://pastebin.com/myUAu10R

Comment: Have you changed any boot options? If possible, pastebin `/var/log/kern.log`. It looks like there is an embedded controller and WMI event attached with the brightness keys. Are your brightness keys Fn+F7/F8?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks! Also you could take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74898/cant-adjust-using-brightness-keys-on-an-hp-dv6-6080-and-cant-using-projector-s)